# JSON in nodejs doesn't give me all informations

Tags: node.js, json

I try to get some data from API.
In postman I get

```
{
    "data": {
        "platformInfo": {
           someInfos
        },
        "userInfo": {
            someInfos
        },
        "metadata": {},
        "segments": [
            {
                someInfos,
                "stats": {
                    "timePlayed": {
                        "rank": null,
                        "percentile": 77.0,
                        "displayName": "Time Played",
                        "displayCategory": "General",
                        "category": "general",
                        "metadata": {},
                        "value": 3404734,
                        "displayValue": "39d 09h 45m",
                        "displayType": "TimeSeconds"
                    },
                     other stats here

                }
            }
        ],
        "availableSegments": [],
        "expiryDate": "2019-12-15T17:19:18.9051055Z"
    }
}
```

but in node.js I've got

```
{
    "data": {
        "platformInfo": {
           someInfos
        },
        "userInfo": {
            someInfos
        },
        "metadata": {},
        "segments": [Object],
        "availableSegments": [],
        "expiryDate": "2019-12-15T17:19:18.9051055Z"
    }
}
```

How you can see diffirence is in "segments".

My get request from node.js:

```
        var request = require('request');
        var JsonFind = require('json-find');
        var url = 'https://public-api.tracker.gg/v2/csgo/standard/profile/steam/steamId';
        request.get({
          url: url,
          json: true,
          headers: {'TRN-API-KEY': 'Some api-key'}
        }, (err, res, data) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Error:', err);
            // error, reject
            reject(err);
          } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
            console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
            reject(res.statusCode);
          } else {
            console.log(data.segments)
            }
          })
```

Where I use console.log(data.segments), I' ve got undefined object.
I don't where problem is. Probably the problem is a big data in segments.
Of course code works for co

Comment: `data` (from `(err, res, data)`) is the entire object decoded from the JSON (the one you listed as received by using Postman). The JS code should be `console.log(data.data.segments)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is that the default depth of accessing using console.log  is 2
you have two ways to handle it

1. `console.log(JSON.stringify(x, null, 2))`
   where 2 is the number of spaces to use for indentation.

   2.`require('util').inspect.defaultOptions.depth = null`
   and this will remove any limit on depth

Answer (score -3):

You are giving here **Invalid authentication credentials**
Please check for valid credentials
and then again try

you will get an api key like :
TRN-Api-Key: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
example :
TRN-Api-Key: 17012661-57fa-45fa-bbdf-xxxxxxxxxxxx